# simple Elasticsearch nested search query

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have documents in ES (Tweepy JSON) like this

```
{
  "_source": {
    "id": 792477813014224900,
    "metadata": {
      "iso_language_code": "en",
      "result_type": "recent"
    },
    "retweeted": false,
    "retweet_count": 330,
    "user": {
      "id": 149250899,
      "listed_count": 0,
      "protected": false,
      "followers_count": 347,
      "entities": {
        "description": {
          "urls": []
        }
      },
      "screen_name": "Zwido_"
}
```

And I would like to search and query one full document based by user_name field.
I tryied this code

```
{
            "nested": {
                "path": "_source",
                "score_mode": "avg",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "text": {"_source.user.user_name": user}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

But it doesn't work and I received error

```
TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to parse search source. unknown search element [nested]
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `_source` field + you're missing a `query` at the top-level, do it like this instead.

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "user",
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {"user.screen_name": user}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If your `user` field is not of `nested` type, then you can simply do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "user.screen_name": user
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, It's working. I added "size" : 1, to filter just one query. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the elasticsearch documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) you should change the mapping of your data to tell elasticsearch that it is nested object. Once that is done then you can query the object.

Comment: I believe @Val answers works like charm but I received error that 'user' is not type nested. So I googled and tryied update _mappings but I noticed that I can not change mapping without losing data from index. I am screwed right now, any suggestions?

Comment: as far as i have read you will have reindex the data for changing mapping but downtime is an issue you can refer here about aliasing your indices to prevent downtime.